# Is simple extension separable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

We know that if $K/F$ is finite and separable, then $K/F$ is simple. I wonder if the converse is also true ?

Comment: What about $\Bbb F_2(x)\supset\Bbb F_2(x^2)$ ?

Comment: @Lubin Oh,right ! Thank you